# updateViewConstraints and orientation handling

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout, constraints, uiinterfaceorientation

I've some questions about the  `updateViewConstraints` method:

1. Why is `updateViewConstraints` called twice at the loading of the view controller? And why is it called when the view controlle is dismissed?
2. In iOS 7.1 `updateViewConstraints` is not called when the orientation changes. In iOS 8 it is. Now I'm calling `updateViewConstraints` in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration`, which is up to iOS 7 only.
3. Where should one add/remove subviews/child view controllers? Currently I'm doing this in `updateViewConstraints` because `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` is called after `updateViewConstraints`. The views have to be available before the new constraints are added.